# Screen Stuck with ubuntu 12.04 on DELL optiplex 7010 with biolinux

Tags: 12.04

The screen stops working after a while on my Dell machine (Optiplex 7010) I'm using Biolinux (ubuntu 12.04) ,it first was hard to install 12.04 as after the installation loading the screen went red and green blocks but after restarting the installation many times it works, after installing the operating system the screen stuck after launching any program and I don't know what to do !!!!

Comment: Don't be angry on the Askubuntu. You wrote `!!!!` because nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the proprietary drivers for your video card?

If not, try it.

Go to your dash, type in additional drivers, and then open additoinal drivers. If you see a driver that ends in (proprietary) try it. I was experiencing similar problems on my dell optiplex 7010 and this resolved them.

Good Luck!